# load JSON Object Dynamically for C3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, json, c3

I am trying to create a C3 bar chat. Need to pass the JSON dynamically.

JSON: JSONdata

```
{ "applicationName": "app1", "frequency": 1 }, { "applicationName": "app2", "frequency": 54 }, { "applicationName": "app3", "frequency": 3 }
```

I have the below code and it does not work. 
Tried using JSONdata.stringify() too.

```
var chart = c3.generate({

                        data: {
                            type: 'bar',
                            json: [
                                JSONdata                          
                            ],
                            keys: {
                                x: 'applicationName',
                               value: ['frequency']
                            }
                        },
                        axis: {
                            x: {
                                type: 'category'
                            }
                        },
                    bar: {
                        width: {
                            ratio: 0.5
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: What's `JSONdata` contain?

Comment: it's not a valid JSON !

Comment: Add contents of your JSONdata.

Comment: JSONdata has valid content. Looks something like below:

Comment: { "applicationName": "app1", "frequency": 1 },
  { "applicationName": "app2", "frequency": 54 },
 { "applicationName": "app3", "frequency": 3 },

Comment: This is valid json : [{ "applicationName": "app1", "frequency": 1 },
 { "applicationName": "app2", "frequency": 54 },
 { "applicationName": "app3", "frequency": 3 }]

Simply use json: JSONdata

Answer (score 1):

All that had to be done was:

```
var config = {};
config.data = {};
config.axis= {};
config.data.json = JSONdata;
config.data.type = 'bar';
config.data.keys=  {
                     x: 'applicationName',
                     value: ['frequency']
                    };
config.axis =  {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category'
                    }
                };
 config.bar = {
                    width: {
                        ratio: 0.9
                    }
                };

  var chart = c3.generate(config);
```